# Express.js Event emmiter and socket.io: Emmit/Send data on event listeners to specific sockets having specific socket.id

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, events, socket.io

Over my personal project I fire some events for example:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
//Some other doe goes there
emmiter.emit('some-event');
```

Also I use the following pattern in order to create a controller in a file `my_controller.js` that defines my applications routes:

```
const express = require('express');

function MyController(expressApp,emmiter){

  const router = express.Router();

  router.get('/someendpoint',function(req,res,next){
     res.end("Hello");
  })

  emmiter.on('some-event',function(){
    //Send hello there
  });

}

module.exports=MyController;
```

Ans I have a main.js file that serves ad application bootstraping-express.js initialization:

```
const express=require('express');
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const MyController=require('my_controller.js');

const app=express();
const server=app.listen(config.http.port,function(){
  console.log("Listening over port: "+config.http.port);
});

const websocket=io.listen(server);
const emmiter=new EventEmitter();

const controller=new MyController(app,emmiter);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
      console.log('user disconnected');
    });

    //I can emmit or send stuff there
});
```

So I am asking how I can send/emmit a message over a specific socket when my application emits events without the need of multiple listeners?

Comment: Are you looking for a different design approach?

Comment: No I am looking for a way to emmit stuff during a websocket with minimum listeners either in socket.io or event listener.